# Github branches never in sync even though they should be

Tags: git, github

I have two branches staging and master. They are in sync no differences.

Using github.com I follow these steps.

1. I create a new branch called `Tim`
2. make edits
3. commit edits to that branch `Tim` I just made
4. merge that `Tim` to the `staging`
5. merge `staging` into `master`

After step 5, I go to the `staging` branch and it says it's out of sync with the `master` branch, `master` branch is ahead by one commit.
I look to see what was changed and it was the `staging` merge.
If I sync `master` to `staging`, then `master` says it's behind one commit and the cycle never ends, they don't ever sync.

What am I doing wrong? I have a video showing this if it's helpful
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by 'sync'? they will be different becuase they will always have a different commit history but you can merge master back to staging and it should be in sync.

Comment: In steps 4 and 5, do you mean create a PR on GitHub and complete it? (I'm not sure how you "merge" on GitHub without a PR.) Hint: you can merge with fast-forward outside of GH, and this is likely what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

"even though they should be" No, they shouldn't. That's not what "merge" means.

If you have this situation:

```
A -- B -- C <- master
 \
   --- X -- Y <- staging
```

Then if you merge `staging` into `master`, you have this:

```
A -- B -- C -- M <- master
 \            /
   --- X -- Y <- staging
```

As you can see, there is now a new commit M — *the merge commit*. And it is on `master` but not on `staging`. So `master` is ahead by 1. And that is exactly what you (should) expect.

Comment: Thanks @matt so what's the proper way to keep a staging branch and live branch in sync?

Comment: I don't know what "in sync" even means to you. A branch is just a name for a commit. If they are to be identical you should give two names to one commit. But then, if they are always supposed to be exactly the same, why are there two different branches?